# Почему оператор break не работает в конструкции тернарного оператора?

Tags: javascript

```
(locale == "ru" || locale == "en" || locale == "it")
    ? break
    : alert("Please, input correct language!") ;
```

Поитогу на браузере в логах пишет что

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'break'.

`break` для выхода из бесконечного цикла. В чем же может быть причина?
А если в обычно `if` то все ОК.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, как вы используете тернарный оператор является плохой практикой. Тернарный оператор по определению *возвращает* один из своих аргументов. Аргументы [тернарного оператора](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-conditional-operator) должны быть [*выражениями*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-assignment-operators) допустимыми в правой части оператора присваивания. Конструкция `break` выражением не является. И это вовсе не ошибка.

Точно так же у вас не получилось бы засунут в аргумент тернарного оператора конструкции вроде `return`, `if`, `for` и прочие.

Решение простое: используйте обычное ветвление вместо тернарного оператора.

```
if (locale == "ru" || locale == "en" || locale == "it") {
    break;
} else {
    alert("Please, input correct language!");
}
```

Если вам так сильно хочется сократить количество используемых символов, то можно использовать `if` без `else` и без необязательных фигурных скобок:

```
if (locale == "ru" || locale == "en" || locale == "it") break;
alert("Please, input correct language!");
```

Этот код будет работать, но я бы не рекомендовал вам его использовать в реальных приложениях из-за плохой читаемости.

Comment: А что же такое выржаение, в том всмысле, в котором оно вложено для тернарного оператора?

Comment: Я добавил в ответ ссылку на стандарт, описывающую семантику выражения допустимого в условном (тернарном) операторе. см _AssignmentExpression_ в http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-assignment-operators